# Conditional formatting or data validation if one cell is blank AND the other is not

Tags: excel

I feel like there must be a simple solution to this, despite google not yielding anything.

Basically, I an excel newbie and I am creating a complex construction estimates sheet, where there are 10 tabs for our 10 large categories of work (plumbing, etc). The user then selects a sub- category (i.e., chilled piping) and enters hours under the Journeyman, Apprentice, Foreman, etc categories since every union and type of work gets different pay. All these 10 tabs are summed together to create a pricing sheet that shows sum of labor hours and sum of pricing by category ("Plumbing: 4.5 hours, $400", "Foundation: 300 hours, $7810").

The problem is, the user MUST select a subcategory from the drop down as well as put in hours or else the pricing breaks since the formula uses a VLOOKUP to find the correct price for each subcategory. The summary tab will show count of hours but a blank in pricing if this isn't done ("Plumbing: 4.5 hours, $-").

I'm trying to force the user to pick a subcategory if they've typed in hours into the columns, or make the sheet return an error on the summary tab if the hours aren't blank but the pricing is. Don't care either way. I've tried conditional formatting and data validation but haven't been able to figure out how to express: "If cell B1 is not blank, and cell C1 is, highlight C1 red/return error message."

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

apply this in another cell like if(b1="",1,0) and make your data validation through that cell.